# How to manipulate the string using stream API in Java. which api method is suitable

Tags: java

How to manipulate the string using stream API in Java. which api method is suitable.

I am trying some Java 8 features.

so lets say I have list of string

```
List<String> str = Arrays.asList("Hello World","Welcome America");
        List<String> res = str.stream()
                          .map(st -> st.split(" "))
                          .collect(Collectors.)); // here after Collectors what should I use.
```

my output should be like : [Hello Welcome, Wrold America]

hwrw by using `map` i am transforming the list but I am not getting any method to collect that. any help so i can do it by using stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very clean or efficient, but here's one way:

```
List<String> res = IntStream.range(0, str.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> str.stream()
                .map(s -> s.split(" ")[i])
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/Jca4ha)

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works. let me see what Intstream do. also why this is not right aproch to do. i know the complexity and both traditional way and by using stream api. can you please give some light on that.